# Functional Gradient Descent and Functional Taylor Expansion

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, gradient-descent

The questions are based on the below screenshots.

1. Can somebody explain how the functional Taylor expansion is related to a "standard" function Taylor expansion? In particular, I am concerned with this term
   $$
   C(F+ \epsilon f) = C(F) + \epsilon <\nabla C(F), f>
   $$
   where $<\cdot{}, \cdot{}>$ is some suitable inner product.
2. Why is it in general not possible to choose $f = - \nabla C(F)$?

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Source: Functional Gradient Descent for combining hypotheses by Mason et al. (1999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's analogous to a Taylor expansion provided you define a notion of continuity and functional derivative (like Gateaux or Frechet derivatives). Once you define such concepts given a functional with some properties you can derive a Taylor expansion (first order in the case you proposed) in the same way you would do for a normal real valued function.
2. Not sure about the question here, but when you have a functional you want to minimize you want to find its stationary points (as necessary condition), something like this leads to

$$
\nabla C(F) = 0
$$

you can either solve this equation in closed form, if you can, or using a gradient flow (continuous version of gradient descent). If $F$ is your unknown function the gradient flow takes the form

$$
\partial_tF = - \nabla C(F)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer re 1. So you mean e.g. for Taylor Expansion of the form $f(a+h) = f(a) + f´(a)\cdot{}h$ this would translate in my question from above (informally) to $f(\cdot{}) = C(\cdot{})$, $a=F$ and $h = \epsilon f$.

Comment: Yes, but I think you could see a better resemblance with Taylor expansion if you consider a multivariate function $f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ + directional derivative. In such a case you would end up with: $$f(x + \epsilon u) = f(x) + \left\langle \nabla f, u \right\rangle \epsilon.$$ The expression is the same as your one, however what is "unclear" is the meaning of each symbol, to give those a meaning you need to use the concepts I mentioned in my answer.